# N Log Test Output to XML Format?

Tags: xml, selenium, visual-studio-2015, nunit

Forgive me for the general ness of the question but can someone point me to some documentation or offer advice on how to receive N Log Test Output from N Unit in an xml format. The reason I am asking is I want to convert this xml over to HTML using Report Unit but after I run my tests all I receive is a log file and I keep reading online about people who have their N Unit Test Results generated out to XML.

For example here is a test I have successfully ran in visual studio using N Unit.[image]

Here is my test case in which I have used the Logger Class from N Log
[image]

But all I am getting is a txt file with my log statment in it even though I have tried configuring the NLog.Config file with the proper xml.[image]
[image]

If you notice the NLog Config file I have tried updating the filename from ".log" to xml but that did not work either. I apologize for the scatteredness of the question but am I missing something basic? Shouldn't n unit tests be generating an xml result?

UPDATE: After getting clarifiaction please see below:

I have now access nunit3-console from the command line can you please advise what i Need to do from here to run specific tests to generate the xml file?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, NLog has nothing to do with NUnit even though they both start with N. The `Test.log` file will just contain any logging that you create. NUnit produces a `TestResult.xml` file with the test results, but AFAIK, the Visual Studio test adapter does not create the `TestResult.xml`.

In order to create `TestResult.xml`, run your tests from the command line using [nunit3-console.exe](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line). You do this by going to your bin directory from the command line and passing your test.dll to the NUnit console.

`C:\src\MySolution\MyTestProject\bin\Debug> "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" MyTestProject.dll`

This will run all tests in your project and `TestResult.xml` will be written out to that directory at the end of the test run. For more info, see the [help for NUnit Console](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)

If you have further questions, add a comment I and I will update the answer for you.

Comment: Thank you! for the input! Please see my updated message above

Comment: I have added info on how to run NUnit console.